# How to enable HTTP gzip compression on Apache/Httpd?

Tags: apache-httpd

I have a Centos 7 installation with apache / httpd running.

I have some large `.html` and `.txt` documents which it serves.

How do I enable `gzip` compression with `DEFLATE`?

---

`DEFLATE` is present.

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES |grep deflate
deflate_module (shared)
```

I added this to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
<filesMatch "\.(js|html|css|txt)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesMatch>
```

Then restarted the server with:

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

---

This still indicates it's not enabled:
http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/

Answer (score 2):

insert this code on your htaccess file from website in source "htdoc" or "www", if you not have htcaccess, you want to create it:

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml: 

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

everything should go fine.

Answer (score 1):

Put this line into your VirtualHost:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
```

If you want some exclusions, then for instance:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip
```

---

For complete information about the `DEFLATE` module, [visit this page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html).